# What is the voltage from which a normal humans starts feeling electric shock?

Tags: electricity

1. I want to ask what is **maximum voltage or amperage or both** which a normal human can not feel.
2. There is no feel of shock when we touch any terminal of a 12 V Battery what is the reason behind it?

Comment: try connecting the 12 volts to two spots on your tongue.  see if there is no feel of shock.

Comment: Yeah, a guy in front of me did it but he was pretty fine. He felt nothing. I don't know why, but the battery was fully charged, still nothing happened to him.

Comment: @Saad No, he did not connect a fully charged 12V battery to his tongue and not feel anything. Either he is lying or you are lying.

Comment: really??  when i was a kid, 9v batteries were quite common in electronics of the day (like the "transistor radios" or "walkie-talkies" or a variety of guitar stomp boxes).  the + and - terminals are adjacent to each other about 1 cm apart.  you could quickly test a 9v battery (whether it was completely dead or if there was possibly some life in it) by touching it to your tongue.  didn't hurt much, but you could feel and taste it.

Comment: and compared to the 9v battery, the 12v car battery has essentially infinite current (or zero internal impedance).  it would *have* to light up your tongue more than a 9v battery.

Comment: Maybe this is yet another case of the confusion about what the negative terminal is? You write "touch any terminal". Of course not, you can touch any terminal on a 1000V battery (no, don't try this) without anything happening. You need a _closed circuit_. Maybe your teacher doesn't know how to teach that. (This comment is written after reading the other question this user posted, btw.)

Comment: one thing you can do with a fully charged car battery that you can't do with a 9v electronics battery is do a little bit of welding.

Comment: Buy a variac, do some experiments. Let us know.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QX2bTxc6ac you were saying?

Comment: @Passerby, i was saying ***one*** 9v battery not 7 of them.

Comment: i dunno, maybe [this guy didn't feel anything](http://www.executedtoday.com/2008/07/08/1999-allen-lee-davis-tiny-florida-electric-chair-old-sparky/).

Comment: You won't even feel shock even if you only touch one terminal of something with a much higher voltage. Read http://wonders.physics.wisc.edu/van-de-graaff.htm

Answer (score 6):

### Background

We don't really feel a *voltage*, we feel a *current* (not "amperage"). Because a battery can be approximated by a voltage source, the current that pass through the body can be calculated by [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm's_law), I=U/R, where U is the voltage from the battery and R is the skin resistance.

The problem is that you generally have no idea about the skin resistance. Dry skin can have up to 100k or more, but there is no lower limit. If you stick sharp probes straight through your skin, you'll get an almost perfect conductivity.

### What is the lower voltage?

Remember that we actually feel a *current*, and the current is related to the voltage and resistivity. It doesn't take a high current for the human body to register it, and instead of reading through [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_shock) for you, I simply decided to test it.

The part of my body with the least resistance is my tongue. I hooked a voltage source up to my tongue and I could easily detect 1 volt. Less than that, maybe, but I would have to have someone help me with a blind test.

When trying the same probes on my slightly moist fingers, I could detect a voltage of around 15-20 volt.

### What are you doing wrong?

I suspect that you confuse *earth*, *ground*, and *negative*. A circuit must be closed to flow. A battery is not a bucket of water that you can pour electrons from, even though a lot of teachers and texts out there apparently wants you to believe that. There must be a path of low resistance between the positive terminal of a battery and the negative terminal *on the same battery* for any current to flow *from that battery*.

If you connect the positive terminal (+) on a 12 volt battery to one side of your friend's tongue and then negative terminal (-) on *the same battery* to the other side of your friend's tongue, I can guarantee you that he will feel it.

I can, however, not guarantee that he will still be your friend.

Comment: I know about Resistance. But I have heard that a normal dry skin can withhold a 25 V DC & 50 V AC without feeling anything. Is it true or false?

Comment: It's often true, but not always. There's no such thing as "normal" skin, really.

Comment: @Saad The part that says 25V DC is probably true. I don't feel anything when I hold the 2 terminals of a 22.2V battery.

Comment: It's somewhat simplistic to say you feel current. Static electricity tends to zap through the nerve endings which is of course painful. And, no, the resistance of your blood vessels is not zero or even close to it. But it's far less than skin, hence medical SELV is 24V.

Comment: @pipe Resistance of the skin varies, of course, by distance. Typically I find between thumbs in tens of kilo-ohms range. There are different ratings for lethality depending on contact points. Keep one hand in your pocket when working with live circuits.

Comment: @Barleyman This whole question is extremely simplistic, so a full discussion about it is probably not meaningful. :P

Comment: The premise that you "don't feel voltage you feel current" is wrong.  There is no current without a voltage, so trying to separate the current from the voltage of a shock is nonsense.  Technically what you feel is power (watts) which is V*I = V^2/R (notice how current gets factored out of the equation.)  The original phrasing of the question is correct and need not be commented on.

Comment: @Tiedye You can absolutely have a current without a voltage. The power is only relevant if you want to calculate the effect from heating, but that's not what's involved here.

Comment: @pipe No, unless we are talking about superconductors, which we are not.